# How to determine whether a user is registered to Realm Object Server utilizing third-party authentication?

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am implementing Facebook and Google login for Realm Object Server.

After obtaining a token I am able to login/register successfully. However, I would like to seed the user's Realm with some data when the user is registered. Since I use a single button for both login and signup I need a way to determine whether the a new user is registered. Although I could check for an empty Realm, this is not desirable since an existing Realm should be synced first. Could the register status be determined in a more generic way?

Furthermore, I noticed that after registration only provider and provider_id are stored in the `__admin` Realm. I understood that more options for `SyncUser` are on the roadmap. Would that also include the possibility of adding more user info when third-party authentication is used? This would make identification of user's a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, we are planning on adding more information to the User object. It would be very helpful if you could add your input on what kind of information (and when!) you need, so that we can take that into account in our implementation. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I just submitted several feature requests on the Github page of Realm Object Server.